# How do I disable file types on Desktop in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, desktop

On my desktop, the files have their type underneath them like this:
[image: Files with type underneath them]

How do I disable this? It's very annoying and takes up too much space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `nemo` and go to

*Preferences → Display → Icon Captions*

and set the first option to `none`:

[image]